# Sprockets - how to require subdirectory in vendor/javascripts

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I've some javascript library that I put in the vendor/javascripts, some of them have more than one files so I split them into directories, like:

```
-- vendor
  -- assets
    -- javascripts
      -- jquery-zAccordion
      -- jquery-file-uploader
```

And I would like to require the directory `jquery-zAccordion` and `jquery-file-uploader` in my application.js and I found: https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/issues/183#issuecomment-2007808.

I would like to ask, it has been 5 month, is there a solution for this or still we have to use the workaround of using a proxy file?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, I've edited the question.

Comment: @RyanBigg, I tried, to include `//= require jquery-zAccordion` in my application.js, it raises the exception `require_tree argument must be a relative path` in development and also raises the same exception when rake assets:precompile. Is there anything different with the sprockets version?

Answer (score 4):

You can include the following in your application.js file:

```
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts
```

And also for the records, you can do the same for stylesheets in application.css:

```
*= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need to extend the assets path like this in your config/application.rb file

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery-zAccordion"
```

@RyanBigg correct me if i am wrong..

Comment: config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/vendor/assets/javascripts" (put the "jquery-zAccordion" in your require)

Answer (score -1):

This should do it:

```
//= require_directory ./jquery-zAccordion
```

Comment: `require_directory argument must be a directory` apparently it won't find the directory.

Comment: @CyrilDD citing the question: "And I would like to require the directory jquery-zAccordion..."

Comment: Obviously I replicated the same context/file structure as in the initial question. I thought you used `./` because the directory `../../vendor/assets/javascripts` would be in some sort of PATH variable, but apparently it isn't